# How to move data from background thread to ui thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, backgroundworker, ui-thread

im a beginner in programming and don't know much. Im using the google directions api to get the distance between two markers. Apparently, it does this on a background thread. Im able to display the received distance on my ui using a runnable, but but im unable to save the distance in a global variable to use in other calculations.

This what my code looks like:

```
public class MyClass {

  private List<Distance> distances = new ArrayList<>();

  private void calculateDistance (LatLng origin, LatLng destination) {
    DirectionsApiRequest directions = new DirectionsApiRequest(mGeoApiContext);

    directions.origin(origin);
    directions.destination(destination).setCallback(new PendingResult.Callback<DirectionsResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onResult(DirectionsResult result) {
        Distance distance = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance;
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
          //adding the distance result from this method to the distances arraylist above
          distances.add(distance);
          }
        });
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Unfortunately my distances arraylist remains null outside of this method. Within the same space where i try to add the distance result to my arraylist, Im able to display the result on a view or Toast. Also, as i add the result to my arraylist, if i check the size of the arraylist within this method, it shows the result was added. But if i access my arraylist outside this method, it's null. But i need to be able to collect a list of distances (NB. this method is called from a for loop) and add each collected distance to my arraylist of distances and perform a calculation outside of the method to get the total distance. Please help me find a way. And please make you explanations as simple or less technical as possible as im a beginner in this field.

Comment: Are you sure it's null outside of this method? Maybe it's actually null on a different instance of MyClass? Java *doesn't have* global variables, so I think there is a mistake in your thinking.

Comment: Sorry i guess i just used the wrong term i thought my arraylist is a global variable. As I admitted, im new to this. Started learning android from youtube last month. And yes its null outside the method above. When i try to access the arraylist from any other methods, it's null. Size 0. Please help me

Comment: How do you call the methods?

Comment: Users can map out a list of destinations. So in their add button's onClick listener, the method above is called and passed 2 LatLngs. First, the latlng of their pickup or their previous destination if theres any, and secondly the latlng of the destination they just added. Example: calculateDistance(prevLatLng, newLatLng). This is the method in the code above. Its supposed to calculate the distance and save it in an arraylist. When they are done, a total distance must be found. So right after calculateDistance(); i run a toast to check the size of arraylist. Its 0.

Comment: Why don't you put that code in the question?

Comment: i love you mehn. The way u're sure its really being saved made me wonder maybe im checking the size too soon after calculateDirections is called. So i added a second destination and the size changed to 1.   man i was going insane

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with android you could look into Android Annotations. You can  make background methods by simply declaring them @Background and then have stuff on the main thread with the @UiThread annotation.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations

It's a very powerful tool to learn. All you need is a couple dependencies

Comment: These annotations are only there to make intentions/assumptions explicit. They do NOT actually switch threads.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the really wasnt a problem. The values were being saved. I was just checking the size of my arraylist too soon after the calculateDirections method is called

Answer (score 0):

> So right after calculateDistance(); i run a toast to check the size of arraylist. Its 0

Well yeah.

`calculateDistance` doesn't calculate the distance. It sends a request to the server to ask for the distance, and it makes a note about what to do when the answer comes back. If you send the request, then print the size of the ArrayList, of course it's 0, because the answer hasn't come back yet.

*When* the answer comes back, then the `onResult` method runs.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the clarification